# CSS class generated by javascript does not apply style

Tags: javascript, css, iphone, safari

I am having really weird behavior when testing page on iPhone Safari browser.

After menu (navbar) is given with CSS class by javascript, the style is not applied

The navbar should be a bit below the top display corner but when scrolled it should stick to the top.
So it is sticky navbar.

The solution is made by javascript triggered in footer onDocument ready.
And it adds a CSS class to the ID of the navbar - called "sticky"

```
CSS:
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

JS
var navbar = document.getElementById("mainNav");
    var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

    function myFunction() {
        if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
            navbar.classList.add("sticky");
        } else {
            navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
        }
    }

offset taken by:
$('body').scrollspy({
        target: '#mainNav',
        offset: 75
    });
```

It works on the laptop without any trouble (CHrome, Safari ..)
It adds the class and does the job. Navbar is sticky to the top.

On iPhone the class "sticky" is also added. But as viewed in the inspector, there is no actual style applied.

The style sheet is loaded correctly tho...

What is happening?

Comment: is js necessary here? did you try using `position: sticky` ?

Comment: Yes it is. The menu is scrollable circa 200px and then when it reaches top then its sticky. So adding and removing class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be closed as it was "solved" by iPhone clears his cache.

On demand and multiple cleaning of cache in settings did not help at first time when coding.
Finally expiration internally forced iOS/Safari to really reload the contents.

It works propperly